# Set value of specific property by custom attribute

Tags: c#, properties, configuration, attributes

I am currently developing a software that will be used by users that should not be able to access the back-end of it all but should still be able to easily change configuration/settings for the application.
I decided the best approach would be a custom "configuration file (.cfg)" located in the root of the final build.
Simple example of the .cfg file:

```
serveraddress='10.10.10.10'
serverport='1234'
servertimeout='15000'
```

Since I wanted the configuration file to easily be extended I decided to use some custom attributes and some simple LINQ.
This does work like I expect it to, but since I am still a novice in .net I am afraid I have not gone with the best approach and my question is therefor: 
Is there anything I can do to improve this?
Or is there just generally a better approach for this?

This is my code for reading the configuration file and assigning the values to it's corresponding properties.

ConfigFileHandler.cs

```
public void ReadConfigFile()
    {
        var cfgFile = new ConfigFile();
        var configLines = File.ReadAllLines("configfile.cfg");
        var testList = configLines.Select(line => line.Split('='))
            .Select(splitString => new Tuple<string, string>(splitString[0], splitString[1].Replace("'", "")))
            .ToList();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(ConfigFile).GetProperties())
        {
            var attrs = (ConfigFileFieldAttribute[])prop.GetCustomAttributes
                (typeof(ConfigFileFieldAttribute), false);
            foreach (var t in from attr in attrs from t in testList where t.Item1 == attr.Name select t)
            {
                prop.SetValue(cfgFile, t.Item2);
            }
        }
    }
```

ConfigFile.cs

```
 class ConfigFile
    {
        private static string _serverAddress;
        private static int _serverPort;
        private static int _serverTimeout;

        [ConfigFileField(@"serveraddress")]
        public string ServerAddress
        {
            get { return _serverAddress; }
            set { _serverAddress= value; }
        }

        [ConfigFileField(@"serverport")]
        public string ServerPort
        {
            get { return _serverPort.ToString(); }
            set { _serverPort= int.Parse(value); }
        }

        [ConfigFileField(@"servertimeout")]
        public string ServerTimeout
        {
            get { return _serverTimeout.ToString(); }
            set { _serverTimeout= int.Parse(value); }
        }
    }
```

any tips on writing better looking code would be highly appreciated!

---

UPDATE:
Thanks for all the feedback.

Below is the final classes!
https://dotnetfiddle.net/bPMnJA for a live example

Please note, this is C# 6.0

ConfigFileHandler.cs

```
 public class ConfigFileHandler
 {
    public void ReadConfigFile()
    {
        var configLines = File.ReadAllLines("configfile.cfg");
        var configDictionary = configLines.Select(line => line.Split('='))
        .Select(splitString => new Tuple<string, string>(splitString[0],     splitString[1].Replace("'", "")))
        .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Item1, kvp => kvp.Item2);
        ConfigFile.SetDictionary(configDictionary);
    }
 }
```

ConfigFile.cs

```
 public class ConfigFile
 {
    private static Dictionary<string, string> _configDictionary;

    public string ServerAddress => PullValueFromConfig<string>("serveraddress", "10.1.1.10");

    public int ServerPort => PullValueFromConfig<int>("serverport", "3306");

    public long ServerTimeout => PullValueFromConfig<long>("servertimeout", "");


    private static T PullValueFromConfig<T>(string key, string defaultValue)
    {
        string value;
        if (_configDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value) && value.Length > 0)
            return (T) Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof (T));
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(defaultValue, typeof (T));

    }

    public static void SetDictionary(Dictionary<string, string> configValues)
    {
        _configDictionary = configValues;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel? Configuration files are a solved problem. You can use e.g. XML or JSON serialization, or .NET .config files

Comment: Thank you for your comment Thomas Levesque. I know about these but the reason I decided not to go with it is because the users that should be able to change the config file has no experience about those formats and I am therfor trying to make the configuration file as simple as possible.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could keep the simplicity of your config file and get rid of the nested loops by loading the values into a dictionary and then passing that into your ConfigFile class.

```
    public static void ReadConfigFile()
    {
        var configLines = File.ReadAllLines("configfile.cfg");
        var testList = configLines.Select(line => line.Split('='))
            .Select(splitString => new Tuple<string, string>(splitString[0], splitString[1].Replace("'", "")))
            .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Item1, kvp => kvp.Item2);

        var cfgFile = new ConfigFile(testList);
    }
```

The new ConfigFile class:

```
class ConfigFile
{
    private Dictionary<string, string> _configDictionary;

    public ConfigFile(Dictionary<string, string> configValues)
    {
        _configDictionary = configValues;
    }

    public string ServerAddress
    {
        get { return PullValueFromConfig("serveraddress", "192.168.1.1"); }
    }

    public string ServerPort
    {
        get { return PullValueFromConfig("serverport", "80"); }
    }

    public string ServerTimeout
    {
        get { return PullValueFromConfig("servertimeout", "900"); }
    }

    private string PullValueFromConfig(string key, string defaultValue)
    {
            string value;
            if (_configDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
                return value;
            return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you phil! This indeed a very nice approach! Just have to add some static values as the ConfigFile dataclass will be initialized in quite alot of places. And a second constructor not doing anything and it looks perfect! I'll play around with it and let you know if I have any questions! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I decided to use a custom "configuration file (.cfg)" located in the root of the final build.

Good idea. For cleaner code, you could use [JSON](http://json.org/) and [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for de/serialization and put the read/write into the `ConfigFile` class. Here is an example that is [live as a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FRYF0H).

The `ConfigFile` class is responsible for loading and saving itself and uses `JSON.NET` for de/serialization.

```
public class ConfigFile
{
    private readonly static string path = "somePath.json";
    public string ServerAddress { get; set; }
    public string ServerPort { get; set; }
    public string ServerTimeout { get; set; }
    public void Save()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, Formatting.Indented);
        File.WriteAllText(path, json) 
    }
    public static ConfigFile Load()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText(path); 
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ConfigFile>(json);
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use it to load the file, change its properties, and save.

```
ConfigFile f = ConfigFile.Load();
f.ServerAddress = "0.0.0.0";
f.ServerPort = "8080";
f.ServerTimeout = "400";
f.Save();
```

We use the `.json` file extension as a convention. You could still use `.cfg` because it's just plain text with a specific syntax. The resultant config file content from the above usage is this:

```
{
    "ServerAddress":"0.0.0.0",
    "ServerPort":"8080",
    "ServerTimeout":"400"
}
```

You could just tell your clients to "change the numbers only". Your approach is fine, as far as I'm concerned. The above is just a cleaner implementation.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Shaun! I will try it out! I think the only problem with this is that the configuration handler is strictly dependent on the format of the configuration file to be correct, correct me if I'm wrong. That could create a problem if the user, by mistake, does not follow the JSON format which in term would not assign any of the lines at all?

Comment: @zatixiz Yes. It would be a problem, if the user didn't follow the JSON format. JSON is more complicated that the format that you're using, so it's more like with JSON that the user will make a mistake.

Comment: I thought so. However, if any of the parameters needs it's value in an array, JSON would simplify that a lot so JSON is definetely something to keep in mind! Thanks again @Shaun

Comment: @zatixiz In the best case scenario, I would create a really simple windows forms GUI that let's the end user edit the config that way. It would just be an `exe` in the root of the folder. Double click it, it opens with three text inputs, and a save button. Cooked. :-)

Comment: The code I postes was just an example, the final configuration file will have 20+ lines of different parameters. The core part of the configuration will indeed be editable in a simple popup window within the application. However, some of the lines in the configuration file should not be visible to some users but at the same time they are given the opportunity to change the non visible ones within the .cfg file if needed :)

Comment: @zatixiz Why not add a *very* simple password-protected area to the form, to keep your end users out of the config file? That would prevent them from breaking things.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would do what Phil did, and store your testlist in a Dictionary.

```
var configLines = File.ReadAllLines("configfile.cfg");
var testDict = configLines.Select(line => line.Split('=', 2))
                          .ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1].Replace("'", ""));
```

Then you can clean up the property assignment LINQ a bit:

```
foreach (var prop in typeof(ConfigFile).GetProperties())
{
    var attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                   .OfType<ConfigFileFieldAttribute>()
                   .FirstOrDefault();
    string val;
    if (attr != null && testDict.TryGetValue(attr.Name, out val))
        prop.SetValue(cfgFile, val);
}
```

You might even be able to call:

```
var attr = prop.GetCustomAttributes<ConfigFileFieldAttribute>(false).FirstOrDefault();
```

Don't have an IDE on me so I can't check right now

Comment: Beautiful @Psymunn ! Works perfectly, just had to change if (attr != null && testDict.TryGetValue(attr.Name, val)) to if (attr =! null && testDict.TryGetValue(attr.Name, **out** val)). Thank you!